# Angularjs 1.0 variable value not increase in view

Tags: angularjs

How to increase variable value in the view in angular js?

I have user function to increase the variable value but got an error in console.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: please add the code and the error message

Comment: we need to see your code before we can tell what is wrong

Comment: share your sample code ,then we cannot help